# IntelliJ: non absolute (relative) path to resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have code like this:

```
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file = new File("resources/file.xml");
        try {
            Document document = new SAXReader().read(file);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and structure of my test module is as follows:

[image: structure of my test module]

The problem is that I get error:

> Nested exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\file.xml

Of course I could change path, for example like this:

```
File file = new File("C:/ws/_SimpleTests/resources/file.xml");
```

and it would work ok, but I dont want to use absolute path.

What should I set in IntelliJ to use relative path?

Comment: What does this have to do with intellij?

Answer (score 5):

First rght-click on the *resources folder -> mark directory as -> Resources root* then 
try reading the file this way

```
InputStream is = TestResources.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.xml");
```

or

```
File file = new File(YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file.xml")
                                                         .getPath());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) to retrieve `file.xml` like this

```
File file = Paths.get(".", "resources", "file.xml").normalize().toFile();
```